# Generate and return docx file to client

Tags: java, ajax, docx

I have an app that generates a docx file base on user input.  It uses Apache POI to generate the docx file and I can get the FileOutputStream from that, the document opens perfectly on a local machine when I write it to a file.

The webapp is using Dojo xhrPost to send the necessary data to the server to generate the document.  What I am wondering is how I get the docx file to the client.

I know I can do it be creating a temp file and passing the location of that file to the client to download, but I would think there would be a way to do it by piping the FileOutputStream straight to the client, which would be much cleaner.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Mr Shiny in this SO question has an example streaming an excel file, should be very similar for a docx:

[How can I get an Input Stream from HSSFWorkbook Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378883/how-can-i-get-an-input-stream-from-hssfworkbook-object)

Except that a docx content type should, probably, be application/vnd.ms-word

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be I'm doing that bit right at least, my problem seems to lie in how I am handling the response on the javascript side.  As it is I can see the response as a bunch of binary but it's not doing anything with it.  Will post a new question as it seems to be a different issue. Might be a Dojo problem.

Comment: @zclark. I think your main problem is going to be with the xhr request. You cannot stream back on an xhr request, it's a common ajax pitfall. Your best bet is to create a hidden iframe and set the iframe source to your docx streaming script. This _will_ prompt the user to download/save the stream

Comment: Many thanks. I went with the iframe option, which in dojo was just dojo.io.frame.send(options).  Only problem that I ran into was getting the iframe to resolve, which I ended up just using iframe.cancel in the event that there had been a previous iframe download and I wanted to initiate another one.

Comment: @zclark. Glad you've worked it out. Thanks for the additional feedback on the procedure, I'm sure someone else will find it helpful